# Android: How to make merge multiple bitmap images to a large jpeg image

Tags: android, bitmap

I am going to merge multiple bitmap images to a jpeg image.

I can make large .bmp file from multiple bitmap images(tiled).
And I can convert it to jpeg file with jpeg library.

But the speed of this process is very slow.
I tested this on my SamSung phone.

It takes about 15 secs to make a large bitmap with tiled bmp images.
Is there any way to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with image manipulation is if you don't do it correctly you end up copying the entire image several times. The challenge is to try to keep only one buffer for the image. Something like the following will be pretty efficient.

```
// create one big bitmap
Bitmap finalBitmap = Bitmap.create(finalWidht, finalHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 
for(int i=0;i<numTilesWide;i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<numTilesHigh;j++) {
        int[] tilePixels = // load tile bitmap into this int array
        // copy tile onto final bitmap
        finalBitmap.setPixels(tilePixels, 0, tileWidth, i*tileWidth, j*tileHeight); 
    }
}
// write the image as a jpeg to the file
finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, /* file stream */);
```

Comment: Thanks. But Bitmap is very large. about 2048*2048 size.

Comment: So Bitmap.create() will be crushed.

Comment: I don't know of a way to build a JPG progressively, but that would be the best way to go. Otherwise, since you're using `.bmp` files, you probably don't need the full 32bits per pixel. Try using ShortBuffer objects (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/ShortBuffer.html) and using Bitmap.copyFromBuffer(), and Bitmap.Config.RGB_565. This will help you represent the bitmap with only 16 bits per pixel and halve your memory consumption. I've done it before, but it wasn't that straight forward. Good luck!